# Why can I add members to FB groups instead of just inviting them?

Tags: facebook

I was under the impression group membership is voluntary - that you can't add someone to a group, but rather you can invite them.

I want to create a Facebook entity that:

1. Is open to everyone - everyone can leave or join at will
2. The only one that can make use X be in the group is an action by user X
3. Will be accessible to users that aren't signed to Facebook

A group doesn't seem to follow rules 2 and 3. Should I use a Fan page ? Or ... what is the best Facebook entity to capture this?

Comment: P.S. - also, I can't create a group without other members except myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want a group. You want a page.

http://www.facebook.com/home.php?#!/help/?faq=16140

> **Since groups look similar to Facebook
> Pages, what’s the difference between
> them?**
>
> Groups and Pages serve
> different purposes on Facebook. Groups
> are meant to foster group discussion
> around a particular topic area while
> Pages allow entities such as public
> figures and organizations to broadcast
> information to their fans. Only the
> authorized representative of the
> entity can run a Page.